# Java SimpleDateFormat not detecting month

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format

I'm using SimpleDateFormat in Java and for some reason it is not detecting the month. Here is my code:

```
     /**
     * Takes a date/time stamp which looks like yyyyMMDDhhmmss on converts it to
     * yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
     *
     * @param timestamp
     * @return
     */
    public static String ConvertDate(String timestamp) {
        if (timestamp == null || timestamp.length() < 14)
            return null;

        String timeString = null;

        System.out.println(timestamp);
        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDDhhmmss");

        try{
            Date date = inputFormat.parse(timestamp);
            timeString = outputFormat.format(date);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        return timeString;
    }
```

Calling this method: `ConvertDate("20190803122424")` returns the following: `2019-01-03T12:24:24Z` whereas I want to return: `2019-08-03T12:24:24Z`

Is there something wrong with my output format?

Comment: Have you tried changing the "yyyyMMDDhhmmss" to "yyyyMMddHHmmss" (lowercase D, uppercase H)?

Comment: It's worth noting that calling `setLenient(false)` causes `parse` to throw an exception in this case.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Not only your input format, your output format pattern string too has a couple of instances of wrong case of pattern letters. Furthermore `'Z'` with quotes is bound to give you incorrect results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong date format string: `DD` (day in year) instead of `dd` (day in month). Change both `SimpleDateFormat` instance to use `dd`:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Therefore you are getting the wrong result.

Comment: give the devil his due, you are faster

Comment: Doing so returned the right month but messed up the day: 2019-08-215T12:24:24Z

Comment: @Smi28 That is a problem of the output formatter not of the date parser.

Comment: You also used `DD` in the output formatter.  You need `dd` in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

As everyone pointed your formatter `yyyyMMDDhhmmss` is wrong, so create `DateTimeFormatter` with valid format

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

And by using java-8 date time API parse it into `LocalDateTime` and then to `UTC` format using `ZonedDateTime`

```
String dateString = "20190803122424";

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString,inputFormat);
```

And then you can convert it into `OffsetDateTime`

```
 OffsetDateTime outputDateTime = localDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

In case if you particularly want `ZonedDateTime`

```
ZonedDateTime outputDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: Thanks i updated the approach to use `OffsetDateTime` @BasilBourque

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but no need to credit me. I suggest replacing your `ZonedDateTime` line entirely with `OffsetDateTime`. Also, I suggest breaking your `LocalDateTime` object into its own line for clarity. So two lines: `LocalDateTime localDateTime = …` and `OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = …`.